# On what nodes should Kafka Connect distributed be deployed on Azure Kafka for HD Insight?

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

We are running a lot of connectors on premise and we need to go to Azure. These on premise machines are running Kafka Connect API on 4 nodes. We deploy this API executing this on all these machines:

> export CLASSPATH=/path/to/connectors-jars
>
> /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/connect-distributed.sh distributed.properties

We have Kafka deployed on Azure Kafka for HD Insight. We need at least 2 nodes running the distributed Connect API and we don't know where to deploy them:

- On head nodes (which we still don't know what they are for)
- On worker nodes (where kafka brokers live)
- On edge nodes

We also have Azure AKS running containers. Should we deploy the distributed Connect API on AKS?

Answer (score 1):

> where kafka brokers live

Ideally, no. Connect uses lots of memory when batching lots of records. That memory is better left to the page cache for the broker.

> On edge nodes

Probably not. That is where you users are interacting with your cluster. You wouldn't want them poking at your configurations or accidentally messing up the processes in other ways. For example, we had someone fill-up an edge-nodes local disk because they were copying large volumes of data in and out of the "edge".

> On head nodes

Maybe? But then again, those are only for cluster admin services, and probably have little memory.

---

Better solution - run dedicated instances outside of HD Insights in Azure that are *only running Kafka Connect*. Perhaps running them as containers in Kubernetes because they are completely stateless services and only need access to your sources. sinks, and Kafka brokers for transferring data. This way, they can be upgraded and configured separately from what Hortonworks and HDInsights provides.